# Map multi-index column to new values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe in Pandas with two index values like this:

```
week_of_year    day_of_week

 1              0
 1              1
 .              .
 1              6

 2              0
 .              .
 .              .
 2              6
 .              .
```

I want to map the day_of_week index to `{'0': 'Monday', '1': 'Tuesday', ...}` but not sure how to access and map the second index.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
d = {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', ..., 6: 'Sunday'}

df.index.get_level_values(level='day_of_week').map(d)
```

output:

```
Index(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'], dtype='object', name='day_of_week')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. That works well. How do I now assign it to the data frame?

When applying the code, I then perform df.head(), but the changes haven't been updated in the dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: @RossDickinson you can't assign to an index, you must craft a new one (use `pd.MultiIndex`). Alternative, set as column temporarily, then back to index